# How can I mount a ramdisk system as a non-root user without sudo (root)

Tags: mount, ramdisk

When I run

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=4096m tmpfs /media/ramdisk/
```

I get an error

```
mount: only root can use "--options" option
```

The directory `/media/ramdisk` is owned by me

```
ls -la /media/ramdisk
drwxr-xr-x 2 username  root 4096 Mar 22 15:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar 22 15:18 ..
```

Is it possible to use `mount` without `sudo` (root) such that I can mount the ramdisk as a user after booting my system? I don't want to have the volume automatically mounted at boot time, but only when I choose for it to be mounted. I believe there is some way to accomplish this with `fstab` but I am not sure how it can be done.

Using root once to edit fstab is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done first by editing `/etc/fstab`, for example I have the following line

```
tmpfs    /media/ramdisk    tmpfs    rw,nodev,nosuid,users,noauto,size=4G
```

0    0

todo: check if rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec are required/sensible

The size of the ramdisk to be allocated later by a user command is set here, as is the `TYPE` and `FSTYPE`. (`TYPE` = first `tmpfs`, `FSTYPE` = second `tmpfs`)

Then a user can call

```
USER=<username> mount /media/ramdisk`
```

this is the command which actually does the mounting. To unmount

```
umount /media/ramdisk
```

which can be run by the user `<username>`.

Change ownership: `chown <username> /media/ramdisk` - todo: check if necessary

Comment: Not useful at it requires root

Comment: @raygozag It does not require root, that is the purpose of `users` in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Who puts that line in fstab? root? If so by definition it requires root.

Comment: The question clearly states "how can I mount without sudo". The mounting operation does not require "sudo", therefore "root is not required to do the mounting operation". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_ZK0t9-llo

Comment: @raygozag I have edited the question title slightly so you don't feel the need to be pedantic about it. If you have a better suggestion for a title which isn't a long explanation which should be in the question body feel free to suggest it.